# Docker using host libraries

Tags: docker

I have hadoop libraries on my host and I want use them in the container rather than having them in the container itself, is there a way I can use my host's libraries in the docker container?

Comment: What benefit would you gain from Docker, if this worked?

Comment: this can work , but this is an anti pattern

Comment: My host is an edge node and I was planning to run a docker for my app on it which can run hadoop utils but seems like there is a lot of overhead lots of volume mounts.env vars and ports which need to be take care to run hive from my docker.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount a host directory on the container so it will be available inside, for example:

```
docker run -it -v /opt/myhadooplibs:/myhadooplibs busybox
```

Now /opt/myhadooplibs contents will be available on /myhadooplibs on the container. You can read more about volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Note that by doing this you are making your container non portable as it depends on the host.